# Padding issue with Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-grid

I got a issue with padding Kendo Ui Grid, the `Grid` covered all a `header`. On a `footer` it has a `Toogle` button, when click the `Toogle` button the `header` will appear. For more specific see two images below.[image: before Toggle]

[image: after Toggle]

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductSubcategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductCategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.NameofBike).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.isSelected).Width(120);
    })

    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .ToolBar(tb => 
    {
        tb.Create();
        tb.Save();
    })
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: can you show html/css ?

Comment: @durgesh.patle I just updated cshtml!

Comment: it got nothing to do with grid.. its your markup and css ..put grid in div with overflow:hidden and min-height will solve the issue..